# How can I check the tagging and accessiblity of a PDF file?

Tags: accessibility

One more requirement for the e-book publication is the tagging of the PDF. The minimum requirement is tagging of `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>` and `<p>`. However I only have Adobe Acrobat DC available and hence I don't know how to check if the tagging actually worked.

If I use the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\title{My title}
\author{My author}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{accessibility}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{This shall be a h1 heading}
    \section{This shall be a h2 heading}
    This shall be a p section
    \section{This shall be a h3 heading}
\end{document}
```

Adobe Acrobat DC shows me:

[image]

So to me it seems, even though I loaded `accessibility`, tagging did not work. Am I doing something wrong, are there better ways to create a tagged PDF and especially how can I check the tagging of the resulting PDF, maybe with Open Source tools?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550523/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So the answer is skip package `accessibility` and use `tagpdf` instead? As you wrote it is not meant for document production, will it break an existing document, or just not creating nicely formatted tags automatically?

Comment: well accessibility doesn't work at all. you can check the issues on their github. Regarding `tagpdf` you can check the source code of the documentation to get an idea about the amount of work involved.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just checked https://github.com/u-fischer/tagpdf/blob/master/source/tagpdf.tex and it looks like it's a 100% manual task in the moment, but of course you are writing, that the final idea is to have tagging in the kernel, which makes sense to me. I think tagging is off the table then for this project, thanks for your support as always!

Comment: I (try to) maintain `accessibility`. As many people have pointed out, there seems to be something in pdflatex that makes it not work (it worked on older releases, which is why I posted it to CTAN...). It would be great if you could file this as an issue! Also, if any one reading has interest in contributing or picking up the maintenance of the package, please get in touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you aren't doing anything wrong.

I (try to) maintain `accessibility`, having taken over from the original author. I tidied it up enough to get it to CTAN, but didn't update the functionality.

Releasing `accessibility` to CTAN has shown that unfortunately there are quite some problems with it. When it was developed back in the early 2010s it worked a lot better, and it looks to be very sensitive to developments in other packages. It no longer compiles a basic MWE reliably. Please believe me when I say "but it worked when I compiled it"!

It would be great if you could file this as a bug at https://github.com/AndyClifton/accessibility/issues.

If anyone reading has coding skills and would like to contribute to the package, please leave an issue there.

Because of this bug and numerous other challenges I no longer think that `accessibility` is fit for purpose, and I will be contacting CTAN to look into getting it taken down.

Comment: Thank you Andy, as requested I filed a bug report at https://github.com/AndyClifton/accessibility/issues/41 to follow up. I wish you best luck and hope that you find a supporter, I am unable to do that, due to lack of skill and time at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing something wrong,

No. Even if package accessibility would work you'd still need a validator to check if the tagging were correct.

> are there better ways to create a tagged PDF

The most convenient way for me is to use Acrobat's autotagging function and correcting a few minor issues afterwards. Acrobat i.e. uses H4 directly so you must correct that manually in order to make your highest rated heading H1.

> how can I check the tagging of the resulting PDF, maybe with Open Source tools?

[PAC3](https://www.access-for-all.ch/en/pdf-lab/pdf-accessibility-checker-pac.html) is your friend. It's not open source but free of charge.