# Creating an ADA Compliant Document with pdftex

Tags: accessibility

What is the current best method to create an [ADA Compliant](https://www.webfx.com/blog/marketing/what-is-ada-compliance/) PDF document using LaTeX and pdftex?

I see postings from [2015](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242303/pdf-x-1a-on-tex-live-2014-for-publishing-with-pod-lightining-source) and perhaps even 2018 on this topic. I recognize that some parts of the work include adding pdf titles and other meta-content.

Does someone have the equivalent of a template (header file) that can be used? What precautions must be taken with hyperref links internally and externally? Should this problem instead be pushed off to an off-line validation service (or run through Acrobat Pro)?

I ask as an instructor developing documents for on-line instruction in courses in the USA, where the certification now requires an ADA validation step.

Comment: ADA requires imho tagged pdf, so see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550523/2388.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Much obliged. Adding pdfinfo content (e.g. via hypersetup) seems to be the easy part. Tagging links is the heavy-lifting part. I have thought naively that href would simply need an [alt=...,tag=...] option but alas I see differently now. I defer that this question could be left open for the best option to build the pdfinfo header or simply closed as a duplicate to the one that you referenced. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer You should not add pdfinfo via hypersetup. You must add XMP metadata, i.e. through [`hyperxmp`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp).