# Is there really no way of providing alternate texts (as read by e.g. Acrobat or PowerPDF) for figures in Latex as of today?

Tags: accessibility

I have searched through various threads orbiting questions of accessibility in Latex. I am not interested in the full glory of a fully structured/tagged document, the only thing that I need to do is to augment figures (and maybe later tables/equations) with alternate texts such that they can be read and modified by Adobe or other PDF viewers.
My understanding is that the `accessibility` package could in principle do this, however it suffers from issues, like not supporting the `fancyhdr` which is a requirement for me. In a minimum example I set up (see below), that package creates text, but no alternate texts.

I have tried both `accsupp` and `tagpdf`, I also tried `pdfcomment` - none of them yield a PDF with the alternate texts readable with Adobe. The furthest I got with `accsupp`, as the reader seems to detect there is some alternate text provided, it just does not show it.

Are there any other solutions I have not looked at? Is there any post-processing hack or something like that? I am a little surprised, because even Word exports PDFs with alternate texts showing up. Adding the alternate texts manually in Acrobat is not an option, as the documents will be changed/compiled frequently.

UPDATE:

Here is an uncompressed PDF with a tag that Acrobat recognizes. The title of the image is "This is the title" and the description (alt text) reads "This is the description":

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/69b4ee447b173ce19e15fa13a03d930220210917073415/113847b5fb92830bf9b4c0c32f6a149320210917073501/ea8762

```
\documentclass [a4paper,parskip,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[tagged]{accessibility}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\gray}[1]{{\color{gray}#1}}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{grafik}
    \alt{hello}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:1}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Some threads I checked:
[Need alt text for images in pdf for screen readers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75102/need-alt-text-for-images-in-pdf-for-screen-readers)

[What is the best package for accessibility tagging?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550511/what-is-the-best-package-for-accessibility-tagging)

[LaTeX accessibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/latex-accessibility)

Comment: Marginally related, insofar as equation accessibility: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454944/is-there-screen-reader-software-or-a-built-in-method-that-supports-latex-equat

Comment: Alt text can be added in various places, I would need an example, uncompressed pdf with a working alt text of the type you want to add to be able to tell you if and how you can do it with latex.

Comment: What happened when you tried `\pdftooltip{}` from the PDFcomment package? There's an approach described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111647/29222). It used to work, but I have not tried it for a while.

Comment: @AndyClifton unfortunately, I do not have access to Adobe Pro which I think is necessary for using that path.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for your comment, I try to get an uncompressed PDF.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have produced an uncompressed pdf via qpdf, I hope it is useful.

Comment: I will look but later. I'm busy for the day.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: that is a tagged pdf, and you can do this with tagpdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your document is a fully tagged pdf. You can get something similar like this (this assumes a current latex):

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{testphase=tagpdf,activate=tagging,uncompress}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\tagpdfparaOff

\tagstructbegin{tag=Figure,alttext=This is a description}\tagmcbegin{tag=Figure}
\includegraphics{example-image.png}
\tagmcend\tagstructend

\tagpdfparaOn


\end{document}
```

I can't show a screenshot, the tool tip doesn't show up, but i can assure you that the tool tip with the alternative text is there.

[image]

Comment: I am interested not in how, but in why. Does it make sense to overload figure `\caption` and use such a trick in all my future documents? Or does it make sense only in images without captions?

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. I have some trouble concerning the Latex version that I have access to (not a current one, unfortunately), I will try to solve this and come back to you.

Comment: Well tagpdf is part of the ongoing project to all LaTeX to create tagged pdf. https://www.latex-project.org/publications/indexbytopic/pdf/. If you want to benefit from the development in this area a current TeX system is required.

Comment: @OlegLobachev tagging only works correctly if you tag the full document. This is not easy, so first read the documentation of tagpdf first. Apart from this: yes, an alternate text should normally always be given, the pdf/UA standard requires that. And often it should be different from the caption as it should describe the graphics to someone who can't see it.

Comment: Thank you again for your effort, I could confirm that this works really well in my context. It is good to see that things are moving in this respect!